# cannot resolve symbol в исходниках студии

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image: скрин]

Просмотрел много тем с похожей проблемой, но решения не нашёл, обычно у всех проблемы конкретно в их проекте, а у меня данная ошибка в исходных классах студии. Я новичок, поэтому постоянно перехожу в исходные классы, чтобы лучше их изучить. И вот в них постоянно ошибка cannot resolve symbol, по скрину понятно, что этих ошибок множество. Вроде как всё равно всё работает, но это меня раздражает)
Пробовал синхронизацию, чистку проекта, пересоздавал проект, invalid cashe тоже пробовал - не помогает. Может кто подскажет как решить мою проблему?

Comment: Как я понял, проблема в том, что импортируемые классы просто не существуют, но как это так, я то ничего не удалял, разве они не должны были установиться вместе со студией? Если нужно самому доустановливать их, то был бы рад, если бы подсказали каким образом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В SDK предоставляются не полные исходники системы - часть зависит от железа и реализуется производителями устройств, ещё часть, как подразумевается, нам в разработке приложений не требуется.

Эти исходники никак не влияют на разработку и выполнение Вашего приложения - они лишь для ознакомления. В приложение собирается только Ваш код. А классы Андроида уже находятся в устройстве в системных библиотеках.

В студии можно лишь отключить подсветку ошибок, чтобы не раздражали и не мешали навигации по классу. Правый клик по скроллбару->`Customize Highlighting Level` и поставить ползунок на `None`. И так в каждом открываемом классе.

**P.S.** Только в своих классах так не делайте - а то узнаете про свои ошибки только при сборке или выполнении.

Comment: понял, спасибо за разъяснение